# How to read through an XML file with VBScript?

Tags: xml, vbscript

Good Morning,

I am hoping someone can help me.  I am trying to cycle through an xml file reading the values as I go.  In the end, what I need to do is find a particular group of information and extract a piece of information from that.  I know that's a little confusing so let me clarify.

Here is a sample of my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<menu>
  <header>
    <listname>Nintendo GameCube</listname>
    <lastlistupdate>09/26/2017</lastlistupdate>
    <listversion>SupraKarma1.1</listversion>
  </header>
  <game name="007 - Agent Under Fire (USA)" index="true" image="0">
    <description>007: Agent Under Fire (USA)</description>
    <cloneof />
    <crc />
    <manufacturer>EA Games</manufacturer>
    <year>2002</year>
    <genre>Action</genre>
    <rating>ESRB - T (Teen)</rating>
    <enabled>Yes</enabled>
  </game>
  <game name="007 - Everything or Nothing (USA)" index="" image="">
    <description>007: Everything or Nothing (USA)</description>
    <cloneof />
    <crc />
    <manufacturer>EA Games</manufacturer>
    <year>2004</year>
    <genre>Action</genre>
    <rating>ESRB - T (Teen)</rating>
    <enabled>Yes</enabled>
  </game>
</menu>
```

Here is what I currently have to loop through and read the data.

```
Dim xmlDoc, GroupName, Games
Dim plot, GameName, GameRating

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
xmlDoc.load("C:\test.xml")`enter code here`

plot="No Value"

For Each GroupName In xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//menu")


    For Each Games In GroupName.SelectNodes("./game")
        GameName = Games.getAttribute("name")
        GameRating = Games.getAttribute("rating")

        MsgBox GameName & " ------- " & GameRating
    Next
Next
```

It is working to read the GameName but the GameRating is always blank.  So my first question is what do I need to change to get the GameRating?

Second, it might be more efficient to somehow change the code to say I want to see the game rating where the name="007 - Agent Under Fire (USA)".  How would that code look?

Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: The `GameRating` is always blank because the XML `Node` `<game>` doesn't include an `Attribute` called `rating`, it does however contain a child `Node` called `<rating>`.

Comment: Try `GameRating = Games.selectSingleNode("rating").text`

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
With objXML
    .SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
    .ValidateOnParse = True
    .Async = False
    .Load "C:\Users\pankaj.jaju\Desktop\test.xml"
End With

'Possible solution to Question 1
Set objNodes = objXML.SelectNodes("/menu/game/rating")
For Each objNode In objNodes
    MsgBox "Game Name = " & objNode.ParentNode.GetAttribute("name") & vbCrLf & "Game Rating = " & objNode.Text
Next

'Possible solution to Question 2
Set objNodes = objXML.SelectNodes("/menu/game[@name='007 - Agent Under Fire (USA)']/rating")
For Each objNode In objNodes
    MsgBox "Game Name = " & objNode.ParentNode.GetAttribute("name") & vbCrLf & "Game Rating = " & objNode.Text
Next
```

*It is working to read the GameName but the GameRating is always blank. So my first question is what do I need to change to get the GameRating?*

Your code is trying to look for `rating` attribute for `game` element which is incorrect. Unlike `name`, `rating` is also an element (child of `game`) and not an attribute of `game`. My solution is essentially finding the `rating` nodes (since you are mainly interested in these node) and then traversing back to its parent (`game`) to extract the gamename information.

External resource - https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd_el_vs_attr.asp

*Second, it might be more efficient to somehow change the code to say I want to see the game rating where the name="007 - Agent Under Fire (USA)". How would that code look?*

My approach is again very similar to what I did for question 1, but now that you want filtered nodes, you have to tweak the xpath to select only the desired nodes. `/menu/game[@name='007 - Agent Under Fire (USA)']/rating` - the xpath will match only those `game` nodes which contains `name` attribute for the given value. Again, I am going directly to ratings node and traversing back to its parent.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the solution you have posted but you have made no effort to explain it, how benefical is that to someone if they don't understand the difference between a `Node` and an `Attribute`? They might have a solution, but are no clearer on the "why" it works, they just know it does.

Comment: @Lankymart - You are right - added some explanation now to make the sample solutions bit more easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You're very close, since, rating is in a text of a child node, not an attribute, the 1 liner fix you needed was:

```
GameRating = Games.selectSingleNode("rating").text
```

However, I had other issues with your script:

- You should add `Option Explicit` to help pick up any typos
- You should rename `Games` to `Game` since that reflects the XML node it corresponds to better
- You should rename `GroupName` to `Menu` since that matches the XML content better (in fact, you don't need this at all)
- You should use `"/menu"` not `"//menu"` in your XPath since you want it to match the top level node, and, infact, since there is only 1 top level node, you should use either `selectSingleNode` or `documentElement` instead of `selectNodes`.
- And, in fact, we can combine your `menu` XPath with your `game` XPath with `/menu/game` and do them both in 1 go, this is why we don't need `GroupName`
- I couldn't see the purpose of the `plot` variable, so, I removed it

Here are all the changes:

```
Dim xmlDoc, Game, GameName, GameRating

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
xmlDoc.load("C:\test.xml")

For Each Game In xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/menu/game")
REM For Each Game In xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/menu/game[@name='007 - Agent Under Fire (USA)']")
    GameName = Game.getAttribute("name")
    GameRating = Game.selectSingleNode("rating").text

    MsgBox GameName & " ------- " & GameRating
Next
```

To answer your second part, we modify the SelectNodes line to include an XPath query to pick the name you want. i.e.

```
REM For Each Game In xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/menu/game")
For Each Game In xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/menu/game[@name='007 - Agent Under Fire (USA)']")
    GameName = Game.getAttribute("name")
    GameRating = Game.selectSingleNode("rating").text

    MsgBox GameName & " ------- " & GameRating
Next
```